# Display Visio page title in page

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I'm working on a multi-page Visio 2013 document, and for consistency purposes I'm looking for a way of including the page title in the `Background` page, so that each page title is displayed within the page of the document.

For example if my document has the following pages:

[image]

Then I would like to display `Foo` on the first page, and `Bar` on the second page, managing the position and the style from the `VBackground-1` background page.

Is it possible to do this in Visio 2013?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the background page:

- Go to **Insert**
- Create a **Text Box**
- Select **Field**
- From Category select **Page Info**
- From Field name select **Name**
- Click **OK**

[image]

This will then display the page title in the page.